# Rearrange listview into two columns on Android (e.g. string list)

Tags: android, android-listview

I am trying to create a flexible layout, using one list of strings as source.
The data could be anything, just assume its an ArrayList as simple example.

So example data (and layout by default, e.g. on mobile is)

Apple
Banana
Cherry
Donut
Eyeball
Fossil

With the two colums it would like this:

Apple    Banana
Cherry   Donut
Eyeball  Fossil

**So to sum up:**

- Single Array list of strings
- Number of columns variable (1 - 5)
- Not XML resolution based (different topic)

I am basically looking for a "aligned wrap panel", but there seems to be not even a normal wrap panel, so I would be happy to simply use two list views next to each other. Or three. Depending on the available space.

So how would you do that? Create a ListAdapter who accepts an argument and only renders every Nth item? In this case, there is only one ArrayList - could this cause problems if I update or remove items?

**EDIT**

This question does not aim at different XMLs for different layouts, I know all about this. how would you do the above in pure code, with a simple bool switch. If pure code is not possible, how with XML (I dont really see how to split up a list in the described fashion, option A is easy, but how do you do B) Also I dont want to create 8 layout XMl for 1 / 2 / 3 / 4 columns... etc... I want to pass an INT with "Nr of columns"

**EDIT END**

Chris

Answer (score 0):

Basically you do your manipulation of the view with providing different layouts depending on resource qualifier. You should read [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html). And you will get the idea how this things are doned.

You can even have a different layout for portrait and landscape for example you can have

in portrait

```
A
B
C
D
```

in landscape

```
A  B
C  D
```

the basic idea is to put toy main_layout.xml in two places
layout for portrait and layout-land for landscape

Answer (score 0):

Please see the [Designing Resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#DesigningResources) section of the [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) documentation in the android SDK.

Comment: Sorry, I clarified. I know all this stuff, the question is more related in the area of "code based flexible controls" then "different layouts" - I can combine the two later, thats easy. I just dont know how to do the above (see edits in post)